# How to get paypal payer details using auth token?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, paypal

I am working on asp.net mvc. I am trying to implement paypal subscription to my website. I have followed this [link](http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/subscriptions/html.html)

like they specified i created a page like,

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="nora@paypal.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Baseball Hat Monthly">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="123">
  <input type="hidden" name="image_url"
value="https://www.yoursite.com/logo.gif">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="return"
value="http://www.yoursite.com/thankyou.htm">
  <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return"
value="http://www.yoursite.com/cancel.htm">
  <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="99">
  <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">

  <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">

  <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="customcode">
  <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="invoicenumber">
  <input type="hidden" name="usr_manage" value="1">
  <input type="image"
     src="http://images.paypal.com/images/x-click-but01.gif"
border="0" name="submit" 
alt="Make payments with PayPal - it’s fast, free and secure!">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using paypal sandbox for testing paypal subscriptions. I am able to make payment and they redirect me to success callback url that i have mentioned in sample page with querystring parameter auth=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX. Now i want to get the payer details like his name, emial address etc. Is there any way to get payer details using this auth parameter. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [GetTransactionDetails API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) along with the transaction id to get this information once your first payment has processed.  You also could query your own system for this information as well if you are using [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am working on asp.net mvc. How to call GetTransactionDetails api means is there any library for c# or need to make any rest calls.

Comment: All of the SDK and Samples code that PayPal offers can be found on developer.paypal.com and http://paypal.github.io/#adaptive-payments-tab-csharp